# How to clear custom dialog fields data in angular jqxscheduler on adding new appointment?

Tags: angular, jqwidget

I'm using jqxscheduler for scheduling appointment. I have successfully created custom fields in edit dialog of jqxscheduler and able to add/edit appointment. But when I'm creating new appointment, data of previous appointment is always shown in edit dialog custom fields. How to clear data of previous appointment on adding new appointment and keep data on edit appointment in dialog fields?

Comment: Please place your code in stackblitz.

Comment: Ask a detailed question with what you want, what have you tried and whats the problem. Dont be shy to show us some code. Check stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8ixzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. this is link to my stackblitz code. Cusom1, custom2, custom3 are my custom fields. When I want to create second appointment, the custom fields in edit dialog contain data of previously added appointment but I want these fields to contain the data only for edit appointment